# backslashes prior to the apostrophe missed mandatory form field

Tags: php, html, backslash, apostrophe

I have created a form in Dreamweaver, using I believe php and html code.

My question is: Why is my form placing multiple backslashes in front of an apostrophe when a mandatory filed is missed?

I have fixed this issue if the mandatory file is not missed by using the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

and

```
// first we'll fix the magic quotes problem with the apostrophe
$province = str_replace("\'","'",$province);
// then pick up all the old values to pass to database on next submit
echo "<input type='hidden' name='province' value='$province'>";
```

It's only placing in the backslashes prior to the apostrophe.  If a mandatory file is missed on the form and via email results, it's even adding more backslashes.

Comment: can you post more code? your html, your php code, etc.  It's hard to debug why something is not working with the code you have provided.

Comment: Instead of replacing those yourself, use [`stripslashes()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)... _BUT_... post more code so that we can help you fix this at its source.

Comment: For instance, somewhere it is likely that `addslashes()` is being called erroneously, or possible a call to an escaping function like `mysqli_real_escape_string()` at a logically incorrect time. Hopefully `magic_quotes_gpc` is not still enabled though; that feature was deprecated many years ago and removed 2 years ago.

Comment: I'm not sure what more code to post...all other code is pretty basic. I don't have any code referring to addslashes() or mysqli_real_escape_string(), I'm very new at all of this.